# Is it worth learning Smarty for PHP templating?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, smarty

I'm building a simple 10-page site using an MVC-like architecture. Is it worth learning the Smarty templating engine?

Comment: I think MVC would be the one that's too much for a 10-page site :P

Comment: The best PHP templating language for PHP is PHP. [Use PHP](http://thephppro.com/articles/pte.php).

Comment: Once you understand how to cleanly use a disciplined template approach, you can use strict discipline in php in the place of an engine.  But if you've never used any template engine, then you should use a template engine, so that you know how to keep templates separate and clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template engines add overhead.

You should only use a template engine if you need to have others create/edit templates and you do not want them to be able to use PHP.

If you are the sole maintainer, defiantly go with plain PHP. If your team can be trusted (they are all devs), stick with plain PHP. If you have designers that don't know PHP or, more importantly, letting them use PHP is dangerous, then use Smarty or another template engine.

That being said, you are wondering if you should learn Smarty. You'll need to learn Smarty if creating templates with Smarty. You don't really need to learn Smarty if you are just implementing the Smarty template engine.

Answer (score 3):

**Smarty** is template engine easy to learn and use, but I strongly recommend learning and  using [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

no need.

a 10-page site is easy to build. if you would like to use Smarty, you will have to spend a little more time to learn it at the beginning~

Answer (score 2):

A templating language is a good choice when you're dynamically generating HTML. Be it Smarty or something else (for PHP), Razor or Forms (for ASP.NET), or something entirely different (John Resig's [client-side micro-templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) framework, perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a decent templating language itself. Unless there is need for advanced features, custom solutions will only complicate what sounds like a fairly simple setup.

Answer (score 2):

I never got around to looking into smarty. Others scared me away saying it was very complex. I use [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org) for pretty much everything I do now, even small stuff. Even if it isn't worth it for a small site I think it's worth learning for the long term - getting a good grounding in template inheritance and blocks is absolutely worth it.

Check this out:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(\$var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

vs.

```
{{ var|escape }}
```

yummy:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
  * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used **Smarty** a long time ago, I would recommend you that it's no need to use Template Engine like that. Smarty slows down the whole system because its core source code is really complex, and somehow unnecessary. If I had a recommendation on Template Engine, I would say:

1) Use some basic and light Template Engine such as **XTemplate**. I'm not sure if it's still developing but it's really useful, everything is in one class file, ready to use. The syntax is also clear and sweet.

2) Write **your own Template Engine**, so that you can customize it on your own that best fits your current system.

But, however, for tiny and small project (less then 5-7 pages) in which you can have a control over everything, then using Template Engine is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what is said above. For a simple site with 10 pages, use PHP on the MVC model or use a lightweight and fast template engine like [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com) or [Savant](http://phpsavant.com/).

That test might be biased as it is published by the author of RainTPL. But anyway I benchmarked several template engines with the Apache ab utility and can confirm these results. RainTPL is fast.